# onCFCRequest seems to be eating my return value

Tags: coldfusion

I have a remote function in a component that's being affected by my Application.cfc - onRequestStart is requiring the user to login. I don't want to move the .cfc into another subfolder - I want to keep it as close to the .cfm as possible so that I don't have to go hunting for the cfc while editing the .cfm.

I think the solution is to use onRequest and onCFCRequest instead of onRequestStart, but in experimenting with onCFCRequest, it looks like the return value has to be boolean.  So now my remote function is returning a boolean instead of the query that it used to.

[Rays' example](http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2009/7/13/ColdFusion-9-fixes-onRequest-adds-onCFCRequest) shows outputting the result, but what about *returning* the result?

Here's what I tried, but ColdFusion balked at the return value not being boolean:

```
public boolean function onCFCRequest(string cfc, string method, struct args) {
    local.comp = createObject("component", arguments.cfc);
    local.result = evaluate("local.comp.#arguments.method#(argumentCollection=arguments.args)");
    return local.result;
}
```

Comment: The problem is: I have another application that is using this same remote function.  So the user isn't logged into the original application where the remote function lives.  I suppose I'll have to move it out into a third subfolder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is this assertion:

> in experimenting with onCFCRequest, it looks like the return value has
>   to be boolean

That's not true.

It can (and should) be "any", in which case it'll return whatever data type the called method returns (serialised so it can be transmitted in the HTTP response, natch).

Comment: Oh, it's because I've got public boolean!  Thanks Adam!

Comment: The solution to my woes was that if I extend a component that's in another subfolder, then I can have the one copy of source code running under two different Application.cfcs, and thus two different datasources.  I didn't need to mess with onCFCRequest after all.